# Sparql query doesnt return all records

Tags: rdf, sparql

when I run this query:

```
SELECT ?x
WHERE {?x <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Ontology>
```

} here: http://dbpedia.org/sparql it return

> x http://dbpedia.org/ontology

but when I run:

```
SELECT ?x
WHERE {?x ?y ?z

}
```

it doesnt return previous record why ?

Comment: I guess, the SPARQL endpoint includes an internal restriction and would never return the subjects of all triples in this triple store.

Comment: Duplicate question posted (and answered) here: http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/15096/sparql-query-doesnt-return-all-records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the public DBpedia SPARQL engine is limited to a fixed number of results, that I guess depend on some internal identifiers, so you last query would return different result sets every time you run it.

Please, avoid the usage of such queries, specially with huge datasets, not only because this concrete limitation in some public services, but also because the time necessary to perform it could be quite long.